# Error message not visible in InfoPath

Tags: infopath

I tried publishing an Infopath form to SharePoint 2013. Unfortunately an error occcured but the error message is not visible (se below screenshot). How can I see the error?

[image]

Comment: any solution you have found?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

An old problem that was never fixed, but you can always see the full error description in the **Event Viewer**, **under Microsoft Office Alerts**

[image: Event viewer]